# How to color DC js bubble chart based on column variable?

Tags: dc.js

I am just checking if we could consistently maintain a single color for specific entries through out all graphs. Is there any way?

-yash

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hint: bubble chart implements [.colors()](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.colorMixin.html#colors)

Comment: Hi Gordon,
Thank you..